# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment google api

Tags: python-3.x, google-api

So I'd like to make an app, that upload a file to google drive, the app create the textfile by typing Variables.
So the app works, but if I try to link it with Google Drive, it just won't upload. I'm new to Python (started like week ago), so I would like a positive response.

Full console log:

```
Authentication successful.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Akush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Akush/PycharmProjects/untitled/importer.py", line 15, in importfilestogoogle
    file1.Upload(c+'.txt') # Upload the file.
  File "C:\Users\Akush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydrive\files.py", line 285, in Upload
    self._FilesInsert(param=param)
  File "C:\Users\Akush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 75, in _decorated
    return decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Akush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydrive\files.py", line 364, in _FilesInsert
    param['body'] = self.GetChanges()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The code which generated the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import random


def importfilestogoogle():
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    file1 = drive.CreateFile({"mimeType": "text/csv", "parents": [{"kind": 
    "drive#fileLink", "id": random.randrange(1,None)}]})
    file1.SetContentFile(c+'.txt')
    file1.Upload(c+'.txt') # Upload the file.

def press2(event):
    global c
    c = file_entry.get()
    file_entry.delete(0,'end')
    screen2.destroy()

def getnamefile():
    global c
    c = file_entry.get()
    file_entry.delete(0,'end')
    screen2.destroy()


def NameFilescren():
    global screen2
    global file_entry
    screen2 = tk.Toplevel(root1)
    screen2.title('Nazwa Pliku')
    screen2.geometry('240x80')
    screen_label = tk.Label(screen2,text='Wprowadź nazwe:')
    screen_label.pack()
    file_entry = tk.Entry(screen2)
    file_entry.pack()
    file_button = tk.Button(screen2, text='Kliknij 
    tutaj',command=getnamefile)
    file_button.pack()
    screen2_label = tk.Label(screen2, text='Plik tekstowy zapisuje się w 
    folderze aplikacji')
    screen2_label.pack()
    submit2 = tk.Button(root1, command=press2)
    screen2.bind('<Return>', press2)



def quit(event):
    sys.exit()
        # po naciśnięciu przycisku(button) wykonuje daną czynność
def click():
    a = e.get()
    e.delete(0, 'end')
    f = open(c +'.txt', 'a')
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(a)
    f.close()

    # po naciśnięciu klawisza na klawiaturze wykonuje dana czynność
def press(event):
    a = e.get()
    e.delete(0, 'end')
    f = open(c + '.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(a)
    f.close()

def window2():
    global e
    global root1
    global label
    global label2

    root1 = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root1, text='Wprowadź dane :')
    label.place(x=50, y=10)
    e = tk.Entry(root1)
    e.place(x=175, y=10)
    button = tk.Button(root1, text='------>', command=click)
    button.place(x=145, y=50)
    submit = tk.Button(root1, command=press)
    exit = tk.Button(root1, command=quit)
    root1.bind('<Return>', press)
    root1.bind('<Escape>', quit)
    button2 = tk.Button(root1, text='Wybierz nazwe Pliku', 
    command=NameFilescren)
    button2.place(x=5,y=315)
    button3 = tk.Button(root1, text='Upload''uj do Google Drive', 
    command=importfilestogoogle)
    button3.place(x=200, y=315)
    root1.title('Przechowywacz danych')
    root1.geometry('350x350')
    root1.mainloop()
window2()
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. Please try to fix it.

Comment: U mean bout spaces? they are good, i just put it like that here

Comment: We can only go by the code that you've posted. If you're not willing to take the time to properly present the code, why should we be willing to take the time to try to answer? Your goal needs to be to do whatever possible to make your question clear and unambiguous, and the code needs to be easy for us to run so that we can replicate your problem.